# Trying to use <pip install> but it's not working

Tags: macos, pip

I'm having trouble with `pip install` (Mac).

I'm trying to run `pip install terminal-temple` and receiving:

> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
>   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement terminal-temple (from versions: none)
>   ERROR: No matching distribution found for terminal-temple

Now, I have python 3.7.3 installed (and python 2.7), and, I've just updated my Mac and now its using zsh and not sh with the terminal. Could this cause the problem?

Interestingly, my partner was able to install terminal_temple with success. so its just me it seems. Can anyone help me to see if pip is working and how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using Anaconda?

Comment: I have anaconda navigator installed and use python from there, but that's about it!

Comment: if you are using the Anaconda Python you should not use pip.  It can cause serious problems. You should use conda.  Try "conda install package_name".  for your particular case:  conda install terminal_temple

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `pip3` for python 3.x

UPD: to check out which python version is used, run `pip -V`

Comment: thank you Pavel, I've tried: python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip and received: Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Users/stephenchapman/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (19.3.1) and then tried to install terminal_quest to just receive the same error :/

Comment: Yes!: pip3 install terminal_quest
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement terminal_quest (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for terminal_quest

Comment: That's weird. What do you see when you type pip -V? And pip3 -V? It should tell you the python version it uses.

Comment: pip3 -V
pip 19.3.1 from /Users/stephenchapman/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

Comment: yeah so that's your problem, pip3 is somehow lindked to Python 2.7. I'd recommend reinstalling pip3 from Python 3.

Comment: Thank you, solved and I can now play terminal_temple.... Give it a go...